# Help with calculus problem

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if someone could help me find the velocity of this quadratic function: $f(x)=-0.08x^2 +0.568x +7.7818$ I already solve it using projectile motion, but I was wondering if I could do it with calculus...

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a graph of the position of a particle, then $f'(x)$ is the graph of the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the position function with respect to time is velocity, so if your position function is $$x(t)=-0.08t^2+0.568t+7.7818$$
taking the derivative yields: $$x'(t)=v(t)=-0.16t+0.568$$
Where $-0.16$ is the acceleration and $0.568$ is the initial velocity.

Comment: But, by doing projectile motion I calculated that the velocity is 13.8 m/s

Answer (score 0):

after the hint above we get $$f'(x)=-0.16x+0.568$$

Comment: But, if I replace the x with -6.9, which is the root where the initial velocity is, it does not give me the same answer as 13.8 m/s, which is the velocity calculated using projectile motion